# ASP.NET + CSS - How do I center elements in middle of the web page vertically and horizontally?

Tags: asp.net, css, vertical-alignment

My web form is pretty simple. It has to have three lines of text/ASP.NET elements. The Master page has a header and a footer. I need to center those three lines in the middle of the page vertically and horizontally, especially if the bottom changes. How do I do this with CSS?

Comment: Which browsers are you supporting? If IE5/6 then the only practical non-javascript solution is the awful single table cell hack.

Answer (score 3):

In your master page you will want a container and center that, then you will want a div for the main content. the raw code would be something like:

```
<div id="center">
   <div id="main">
      <p>This text is perfectly vertically and horizontally centered.</p>
   </div><!-- end #main -->
</div><!-- end #center -->

<style>
   #center { position: absolute; top: 50%; width: 100%; height: 1px; overflow: visible }
   #main { position: absolute; left: 50%; width: 720px; margin-left: -360px; height: 540px; top: -270px } 
</style>
```

This is using the same approach as offered by Damien.  It tends to be the only way to accomplish with CSS alone.  You can probably better solve this with the use of JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: I had hope for this. It works with only one line of text but when I add more it "bleeds" into the footer from the master page.

Comment: <div id="centerSummary">
        <div id="mainSummary">
            <p>Changes Successfully Submitted</p>
            <p>Please note the Record ID below for your records</p>
            <div> <span>Record ID:</span> <asp:Label ID="lblRecordID" runat="server" /></div>
            <div class="spacer3em"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkHome" runat="server">Return to RON Home</asp:LinkButton></div>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: @schenz, your logic doesn't not scale up to various browsers.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE8. I solved it by just doing this on each line:

Comment: @Sam Gentile, to accomplish this you have to have a fixed size for the content.  It is not an easy task to accomplish (if it is even possible for your particular application).

Answer (score 2):

Horizontally aligning things is simple. If the element has a fixed with give it the following css:

```
.element
{
      margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This tells the element to have 0 top and bottom marin and auto-calculate the margin to the left and right.

There is a way to vertically center elements called [dead center](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html). It uses a 50% off-set from the top of the page and a negative margin to bring the content to the center (vertically). Drawback is that your element needs have a fixed size (height and width).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .auto-style1 {text-align:center;}
</style>
```

Comment: this won't address vertical centering